# Is Java Boolean "wrong"?

Tags: java

So, according to wikipedia and others, a `boolean` values should have only 2 states: `0` or `1`; `true` or `false`; `yes` or `no`; and so on...

OK, correct me if I'm wrong, but, Java `Boolean` wrapper let developers have 3 states: `true`, `false` and `null`.

Isn't that wrong?

I know that it could be explained with something like "Boolean is an object" etc etc, but, it would be really great if javac automagically "wrap" `null` to `false`, IMHO.

My point is: this behavior let developers do a lot of crap, because they use `Boolean` instead of a proper object type.

Anyway, what do you think about it? Am I following a wrong line of thinking.. or is it really "wrong"?

---

**EDIT**

I know what is `null`, the differences between `boolean` and `Boolean`, etc etc etc (I have 3-year+ exp with java).

My point is about the concept itself, like in Ruby, for example, if I do something like `if something`, if this `something` instance is `nil`, it will be `false`.

And I'm not saying that Java is crap or something like, I use it everyday.

Comment: *I know that it could be explained with something like "Boolean is an object"* - well that's the idea yes. Boolean actually even extends Object (like all objects) and by design the default value of an Object is null... Making an exception would be quite couterintuitive me thinks.

Comment: null and false are not the same concept and one can't be wrapped into the other. Reference variables need to be able to be null, and combining null with false would be a dangerous thing to do. But please feel free to create your own language which fixes this, and then show how your language is better than Java.

Comment: `null` means that you don't have a value, it's not the same thing as `false`

Comment: There are uses for both two-state logic (`boolean`) and three-state logic (`Boolean`). The third state is often used to mean "not known", "not available" or "not applicable".

Comment: In some languages null in an object type is not available, only for **optional** types, something like `Boolean? idonotknowyet`. Look at Scala if you are linguistic minded.

Comment: By the way, to be consistent, `Integer` should be initialised to 0, as well as all Numbers. By extension, BigDecimal and BigInteger should probably too. And Date should be today by default etc.

Comment: However, still Boolean having 3 states. @HovercraftFullOfEels no thanks. I don't say java is wrong, I'm just discussing a concept. Don't take it personal.

Comment: @caarlos0: I'm not taking it personal. You are stating "Boolean is wrong" but have shown no evidence to prove this so. I am stating that this is not an appropriate question for SO since it invites nothing but debate. But again if you feel strongly that this weakens Java so, create a language. It will be an interesting exercise for you.

Comment: @assylias But that's if you have an `Integer` object. What if you have no object at all?

Comment: In fact what you are saying might well hold for Integer too. There it is even more imminent, as boxing of null does not yield 0 but a NullPointerException.

Comment: @durron597 **IF** Boolean had a non-null default value **THEN** what I said. ;-)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I didn't say it's wrong, I expose a point and ask if it's wrong.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`null` represents the absence of a value, whereas `true` and `false` are definite values.  It's the difference between knowing something, either affirmatively or negatively, and not knowing it at all.  That's one way to think of it.

Technically the reason a `Boolean` can be `null` is because it's an object reference, not a `boolean` value itself, a confusion that [autoboxing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing) might be causing for you.  It used to be that you had to manually create `Boolean` objects to contain `boolean` values and manually extract the `boolean` values from `Boolean` objects.  Since Java 5, the compiler will take care of this for you.

The value of the `boolean` contained by a `Boolean` object can either be `true` or `false`, but an object variable may not be pointing to an object at all, in which case the value of the *reference* is `null`.

Why is there a difference between `boolean` and `Boolean` you might ask?  Well, in Java, unlike a lot of newer languages, the primitive types are *not* classes, and primitives are *not* objects.  When you want to treat them as such, like when you want to pass by reference or call methods on them or put them in collections, you have to box them up in their respective [primitive wrapper classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_type_%28object-oriented_programming%29#Autoboxing).

Comment: That's my point, it would be nice if Java evaluate a null reference for a Boolean to false, just to maintain the 2-state behavior, imho. BTW: I'll accept your answer because it is the most complete at this time, also, my question maybe is not a real question at all. Thanks.

Comment: It's a totally real question.  I think it's a good question, and in many languages, the behavior you're talking about is exactly what happens.  Java is rather pedantic when it comes to types.  It took many years before they even included autoboxing, probably because it muddles the distinction between primitives and objects in a way that's not quite natural, which saves time and boilerplate, but can seem inelegant, as you've noticed.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to say... but looks like some folks don't like it... thanks again.

Comment: Using `Boolean` for `null`  represents the absence of a precise requirement definition. I haven't seen a reasonable usage of  `Boolean` yet.

Answer (score 3):

If the tri-valued nature of `Boolean` isn't right for you, **don't use it**. Use `boolean`. There are times when you need `Boolean`, when you are working with an `Object`-oriented interface. When that happens, you use `Boolean`.

- `boolean` is a primitive type which represents the concept you are describing, a type with two possible values: true and false.
- `Boolean` is different type. It's an `Object` which holds a `boolean` value. If the object doesn't exist, then the **reference** is null. It's not the boolean object which is null, it's the reference to a boolean object which is null.

Though their names are similar, don't conflate `boolean` and `Boolean`. They are distinct types for good reason.

Comment: I think that's not that simple...  if I need a `Map<String, boolean>`, like this https://gist.github.com/4278518 , I can't don't use `Boolean`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a `boolean` which can be two states, it doesn't make sense to use `Boolean` unless

- you need the three states
- you are using an API which means you have to.

In general, always use a primitive if you can unless a) you need a `null` value b) you have to due to an API.

Comment: or c: Need to use a boolean type with generics.

Answer (score 1):

What you imply is that a wrapper should mimic the strict behavior of the primitive 'real' boolean. Thats the problem. A Boolean *is not conceptually the same as* a boolean (note capitalization).

The primitive boolean provides what is described in Wikipedia as a boolean.

The Boolean (java.lang.Boolean) is not called a wrapper just for show. It is conceptually an Object that *contains* a boolean. So references to a Boolean are *references*, nothing in common with a boolean. Thus the rules for *references* apply, not primitives.

Its quite simple and logical if you take this viewpoint.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing with primitive `boolean` and primitive wrapper `Boolean`. Indeed `boolean` can be `true` or `false` only.

`Boolean` instance can hold `true` or `false` too. But if instance does not exist the reference is `null` as any not initialized reference.

Answer (score 0):

`null` means "I don't have an object here". The `Boolean` `true` object is a wrapper around the primitive `boolean true`, but it is still an object. Note that the following code throws a `NullPointerException`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Boolean myBool = null;
  boolean primBool = myBool;

  System.out.println(primBool);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Null makes it nullable , when you create a database for example it has a table with below columns :

Col-1 : Hour (nvarchar)

Col-2 : Minute (nvarchar)

Col-3 : IsDay (bool)

So if the hour is 18 and minute is 00 what is the value for IsDay ? (it is nor true or false) it is null at this time...